# How do I attach a rotating circle to the corner of the car?

Tags: javascript, html

I need the spinning circle to be anchored to the corner regardless of the car's rotation. When you press the keys, the machine moves, turns, and the circle moves.

[image]

Instead, the spinning circle shifts as the car turns.
[image]

Instead, the spinning circle shifts as the car turns. How to fix? Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/Smith37/pen/PoZMjYJ

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
   <head>
      
      <style>
         #test {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            margin:0px auto;
         }
      </style>
      
      <script type = "text/javascript">
      window.onload = function()
      {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

        
        canvas.style.background = "#444444";
        var x = 170;
        var y = 150;
        var x1 = 35;
        var y1 = 35;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const radianCircle = Math.PI * 2;
        var leftPressedFlag=false;
        var rightPressedFlag=false;
        var upPressedFlag=false;
        var downPressedFlag=false;
        var speed = 1;
        var angle = 0;
        var mod = 0;
        var offset = 0;
        var pi2 = 2*Math.PI;
        var step = 0.03;
          
        function main()
        {
          car = new Image();
          car.src = "http://i.imgur.com/uwApbV7.png";
          var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
              draw();
          }, 30);
          
        }
        document.addEventListener("keydown",function(evt)
        {
      
        if(evt.keyCode==38)
        {
        
          upPressedFlag = true;
        }
        if(evt.keyCode==40)
        {
          downPressedFlag = true;
        }
        if(evt.keyCode==37)
        {
           
         leftPressedFlag = true;
        }
        if(evt.keyCode==39)
        {
         rightPressedFlag=true;
        }
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup",function(evt)
        {
        
        if(evt.keyCode==38)
        {
          upPressedFlag = false;
        }
        if(evt.keyCode==40)
        {
          downPressedFlag = false;
        }
        if(evt.keyCode==37)
        {
         leftPressedFlag = false;
        }
        if(evt.keyCode==39)
        {
         rightPressedFlag=false;
        }
        });
       

        let i = 0;
        function draw () {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          i++;
          
         
             if(!upPressedFlag || !downPressedFlag)
              {
                mod = 0;
              }
              
              if(upPressedFlag)
              {
                mod = 5;
              }
              
              
              if(downPressedFlag )
              {
                mod = -5;
              }
              
              if(leftPressedFlag)
              {
                angle -= 5;
              }
              if(rightPressedFlag)
              {
                angle += 5;
              }
           

          x += (speed * mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
          y += (speed * mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle);  
          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(x, y);
          
          ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
          ctx.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
          ctx.restore();
          
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.lineWidth = 15;
           ctx.strokeStyle = "#4F7942";
           dashedCircle(ctx, x, y, 15, offset % pi2, 5, 0.7);
           ctx.stroke();
           offset += step;
          
         
        }
      main();
        function dashedCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, offset, segments, size) {
  
                    var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI,
                        segs = pi2 / segments,
                        len = segs * size,
                        i = 0,
                        ax, ay;
                    var xd = getPositions(i / 100)[0];    
                    var yd = getPositions(i / 100)[1];
                    ctx.save(); 
                    ctx.translate(xd,yd);
                    ctx.rotate(offset);
                    ctx.translate(-x,-y); 
                    for(; i < pi2; i += segs) {
                        ax = x + radius * Math.cos(i);
                        ay = y + radius * Math.sin(i);
                        ctx.moveTo(ax, ay);
                        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, i, i + len);
                    }
                    
                    ctx.restore();
        } 
        function getPositions (i) {
          return [
            x + x1 - (Math.cos(radianCircle * i / 2) * 10),
            y - y1 + (Math.sin(radianCircle * i / 2) * 10),
          ];
        }

      }
       
        

       

      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body id = "test" >
      <canvas id = "mycanvas" width = "500" height = "500"></canvas>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified and added comments in the following code that would probably help. You were not drawing the circle when you rotate the context to draw the car. You just have to draw the circle before restoring the context.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #test {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

        canvas.style.background = "#444444";
        var x = 170;
        var y = 150;
        var x1 = 35;
        var y1 = 35;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const radianCircle = Math.PI * 2;
        var leftPressedFlag = false;
        var rightPressedFlag = false;
        var upPressedFlag = false;
        var downPressedFlag = false;
        var speed = 1;
        var angle = 0;
        var mod = 0;
        var offset = 0;
        var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI;
        var step = 0.03;

        function main() {
          car = new Image();
          car.src = "http://i.imgur.com/uwApbV7.png";
          var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
            draw();
          }, 30);
        }
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
          if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
            upPressedFlag = true;
          }
          if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
            downPressedFlag = true;
          }
          if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressedFlag = true;
          }
          if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
            rightPressedFlag = true;
          }
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
          if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
            upPressedFlag = false;
          }
          if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
            downPressedFlag = false;
          }
          if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressedFlag = false;
          }
          if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
            rightPressedFlag = false;
          }
        });

        let i = 0;
        function draw() {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          i++;

          if (!upPressedFlag || !downPressedFlag) {
            mod = 0;
          }

          if (upPressedFlag) {
            mod = 5;
          }

          if (downPressedFlag) {
            mod = -5;
          }

          if (leftPressedFlag) {
            angle -= 5;
          }
          if (rightPressedFlag) {
            angle += 5;
          }

          x += speed * mod * Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * angle);
          y += speed * mod * Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * angle);

          ctx.save();

          ctx.translate(x, y);
          ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * angle);
          ctx.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
          
          // Added here
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth = 15;
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#4F7942";
          dashedCircle(ctx, x, y, 15, offset % pi2, 5, 0.7);
          ctx.stroke();

          ctx.restore();

        //   The following code was moved above
        //   ctx.beginPath();
        //   ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        //   ctx.strokeStyle = "#4F7942";
        //   dashedCircle(ctx, x, y, 15, offset % pi2, 5, 0.7);
        //   ctx.stroke();

          offset += step;
        }
        main();
        function dashedCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, offset, segments, size) {
          var pi2 = 2 * Math.PI,
            segs = pi2 / segments,
            len = segs * size,
            i = 0,
            ax,
            ay;
          var xd = getPositions(i / 100)[0];
          var yd = getPositions(i / 100)[1];
          ctx.save();

          //  ctx.translate(xd, yd);
          ctx.translate(offset + 35, offset - 25);


          ctx.rotate(offset);
          ctx.translate(-x, -y);
          for (; i < pi2; i += segs) {
            ax = x + radius * Math.cos(i);
            ay = y + radius * Math.sin(i);
            ctx.moveTo(ax, ay);
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, i, i + len);
          }

          ctx.restore();
        }
        function getPositions(i) {
          return [
            x + x1 - Math.cos((radianCircle * i) / 2) * 10,
            y - y1 + Math.sin((radianCircle * i) / 2) * 10,
          ];
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body id="test">
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```